# how to Display time-sensitive notifications in android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-10.0

after restrictions on starting activities from the background in android Q I'm trying to build notification for my VOIP call using developer.android sample code but it's not working can you please help me to fix this issue ?

this code below is sample that I'm using to build time-sensitive notifications :

```
  Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(this, CallActivity.class);
                    PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                            fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                                    .setContentTitle("Incoming call")
                                    .setContentText("(919) 555-1234")
                                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                                    .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true);

                    Notification incomingCallNotification = notificationBuilder.build();
```

Comment: Can you help with


startForeground(notificationId, notification);

I am not sure where is startForeground defined

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on Android 10, you need to request the `USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT` permission. In your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
```

See: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#full-screen-intents

Comment: wow it works out of the box. I have used this thread https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive#java. After calling it from background service. You can setOngoing(true) if not working.